# adding params to a tab to use in an if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ive been stuck on something for a while and ive been trying to use javascript ect but i feel there is a simpler way. 
I need to use an if statement to render a form depending on what tab has been clicked. I realised that you cant do something like `if tab1.checked` as ruby cant do this. However, in the code below, i thought about adding a param to the tab, and using that in the if statement. Is this possible or any other way? code below is my experiment, thanks. Please no javascript suggestions.

```
 <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs"  :checked = <% (params[:uk_checked]) %>>
  <label class="label-header" for="tab1"> UK Address</label>

  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs" >
  <label class="label-header"for="tab2"> International Address </label>

  <!-- <section id="content1"> -->
    <% if params[:uk_checked] == 1 %>
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :address do |fields| %>
            <section id="content1">
                <%= render "address/fields", fields: fields, addressable: addressable %>
            </section>
        <% end %>
      <% else %>
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :address do |fields| %>
            <section id="content2">
                <%= render "address/international_fields", fields: fields, addressable: addressable %>
            </section>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: If the tab changes, does the URL change?

Comment: No it doesn’t .